Moving even elements to the front of an array while keeping relative order
public static void teePaarisPaaritud(int[] a){
    teePaarisPaaritudRek(a, 0);
}

private static void teePaarisPaaritudRek(int[] a, int i) {
    if(i == a.length-1) return;

    if(a[i] % 2 != 0){
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = temp;
        teePaarisPaaritudRek(a, i+1);
    }
    teePaarisPaaritudRek(a, i+1);
}

I wrote this recursive method. The intended function is to sort the int[] by moving the even elements to the front and odd ones to the back, while keeping the original order between the even elements and odd elements.
For example with the input of int[] a = {-1,0,-7,3,10,4,0,2,-1,-5,6} the output should be [0,10,4,0,2,6,−1,−7,3,−1,−5]. However, my code misses the mark by a little and the output I get is [0, 10, 4, 0, 2, 6, -7, 3, -1, -5, -1] instead.
As you can see the 2nd -1 is in the back, but it should be before the -7. I've tried setting the base to if(i == a.length-2) return;. That didn't work, because then the 6 would remain in the end. The issue only arises when the length of the input array is even.

Why recursion? A loop would be easier to code and wouldn't crash on large arrays.

It's clearer and easier to test if you create arrays even and odd that respectively contain the even and odd elements of the array, preserving order, the return even + odd (to avoid mutating the original array) or replace the original array with even + odd, depending on requirements. In Ruby, even = []; odd  = []; [-1,0,-7,3,10,4,0,2,-1,-5,6].each { |e| if e.even?; even << e; else; odd << e; end } then even #=> [0, 10, 4, 0, 2, 6] and odd #=> [-1, -7, 3, -1, -5].

You can change your condition and recursion as follows:
if (a[i] % 2 != 0 && a[i + 1] % 2 == 0) {
    // swap and recurse starting from the beginning
}

// don't swap and recurse

In other words: if the next element is even, then go ahead and swap, moving the odd element to the right; otherwise, don't swap the elements. Your existing approach swaps elements even if they're both odd, which disorders the odd subarray.
Furthermore, restarting the whole process whenever a swap occurs handles cases where a swap isn't performed because two odd elements are next to each other.
public class Main {
    public static void moveEvenToFront(int[] a) {
        moveEvenToFrontRec(a, 0);
    }

    private static void moveEvenToFrontRec(int[] a, int i) {
        if (i == a.length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        else if (a[i] % 2 != 0 && a[i+1] % 2 == 0) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i+1];
            a[i+1] = temp;
            moveEvenToFrontRec(a, 0);
            return;
        }

        moveEvenToFrontRec(a, i + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {-1, 0, -7, 3, 10, 4, 0, 2, -1, -5, 6};
        moveEvenToFront(a);

        for (int n : a) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }
}

I think moveEvenToFrontRec(a, Math.max(i - 1, 0)); would work too instead of restarting all the way from the front, but I haven't checked this thoroughly.
That said, I wouldn't use recursion for this. It's harder to code, has more overhead and will blow the stack if the list is more than a few thousand items. Recursion is appropriate for logarithmic divide and conquer problems like binary search and balanced tree traversals.
The time complexity of your recursive algorithm is quadratic. A more efficient algorithm is to use a bit of extra space and loop over the array multiple times:
class Main {
    public static void moveEvenToFront(int[] a) {
        int[] cpy = a.clone();
        int i = 0;

        for (int n : cpy) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                a[i++] = n;
            }
        }

        for (int n : cpy) {
            if (n % 2 != 0) {
                a[i++] = n;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {-1, -2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        moveEvenToFront(a);

        for (int n : a) {
            System.out.print(n + " "); // => -2 0 2 4 -1 1 3 5
        }
    }
}

This can be optimized further, and the allocation cost may make it less efficient on very small arrays than the allocation-free quadratic approach.
Here's a quadratic iterative version, non-optimal but shared for comparison to OP's recursion:
public static void moveEvenToFront(int[] a) {
    for (boolean swapped = true; swapped; ) {
        swapped = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i] % 2 != 0 && a[i + 1] % 2 == 0) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

Merge sort mentioned in this answer also seems good, linearithmic and constant space. The intuition there is that the base case element of 1 is already ordered properly, then when merging two subarrays, relative order is maintained and it's easy to append the even element subarray first.

Quadratic is pessimistic. There is a linearithmic in-place solution.

@user58697 I don't doubt it--I'm not suggesting the quadratic is optimal, just that it exists as an alternative to OP's original recursion. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a linear in place with some clever index arranging.

I'd be very surprised, honestly.

I know for loops would be better, but it is a school assignment where we are required to use a recursive  approach. but the proposed if statement still gives me the wrong answer. the first -1 moves to be the 2nd element and then just stays there. I am also not allowed to use for loops.

@user1263607 Thanks, yeah, that's a common constraint, but it's still worth pointing out the issues with recursion. Good catch on the bug, I think I've fixed it, and included runnable code. Please try it and let me know how it goes.

@ggorlen The code seems to work as intended. Thanks!

I am aware you want to use recursion but I feel you should also use a for loop.
import java.util.*;

public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void teePaarisPaaritud(int[] a) {
        teePaarisPaaritudRek(a, 0);
    }

    private static void teePaarisPaaritudRek(int[] a, int i) {
        if (i == a.length - 1)
            return;

        if ((a[i] & 1) == 1) { // this is a small java bitwise trick to help faster code checks the same thing 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if ((a[j] & 1) == 0) { 
                    int temp = a[j];
                   
                    for (int k = j; k > i; k--) {
                        a[k] = a[k - 1];
                    }
                    a[i] = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        teePaarisPaaritudRek(a, i + 1);
    }
}


Thanks for the answer, but this is still recursive. How are you addressing OP's main concern?

I think the user wants to make it recursive

I think so too but it seems like your text says you're suggesting not doing that. Adding a for loop here replaces one recursive call but the overall algorithm is still recursive, sort of half in, half out, with an explanation of why it's better or how it solves the problem.

Unfortunately i have to use a recursive approach per my teachers request. I am not allowed to use any type of for loops.

if(a[i] % 2 != 0){

This line switches the elements if the current index is odd, regardless of if the next index is odd or not. You also need to take that into consideration when revising the condition.

First of all, this problem is a merge sort in disguise. The comparator which compares only a least significant bits will sort evens before odds, and since the merge sort is stable the relative order is kept.
That said, it can be done marginally faster (still O(n log n) though) and in-place. In a D&C setting it is very important to think about the last stage of an algorithm. Consider that you have two adjacent ranges, each already arranged as required:
    eee...eeooo...ooeee...eeooo...oo
    |       |       |       |       |
    v       |       v       |       v
    first   |       mid     |       last
            v               v
            lpp             rpp

(lpp and rpp being left and right partition points respectively).
Now, to arrange such array in the required order, all you need to do is to
    rotate(lpp, mid, rpp)

The only remaining piece of the puzzle is to figure out what rotate should return. Long story short, its return value shall be a partition point, an index of the first odd value. Try to understand why it is important, and how it shall be used.
